# Magento 2.2.6 Web Setup Wizard not working

Tags: magento2.2.6, web-setup-wizard

I am using the Magento 2.2.6(CE).

In Admin Panel, System => Tools => Web Setup Wizard redirect to the following url

> Url: BASE_URL/setup/index.php/session/unlogin

[image]

How to solve this issue?

Thanks in Advance.